# Find values in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables 'student' & 'book'

student has - **Student_ID | name |  age**

book has    - **ISBN | book_name | subject | student_ID**

I need to find ***student_ID,student_name,age*** of students who has ***mathematics & computer*** in their relative **subject** columns in book table.The tables aren`t joined btw.Can anyone show me the right SQL query for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a  join between the table and a filter for the subject  checking that the row involved  contain 2 distinct suject

```
select a.student_ID,a.student_name,a.age
from  student a
inner join book b  on a.student_ID = b.student_ID 
where b.subject in ('mathematics', 'computer')
group by a.student_ID,a.student_name,a.age 
having count(distinct subject) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  a.student_ID
,       a.student_name
,       a.age
from    student a
join    book b  
on      a.student_ID = b.student_ID 
where   b.subject like '%mathematics%'
        or b.subject like '%computer%'
group by
        a.student_ID
,       a.student_name
,       a.age
having  count(distinct case when b.subject like '%mathematics%' then 1
              when b.subject like '%computer%' then 2 end) = 2
```